# How to remove "Google Play Protect" warning?

Tags: android

Google has added a security system for apps that are not downloaded from the Google Play called "Play Protect". It is possible that the Mobile Tracker Free application is detected as potentially dangerous.

To prevent the app from being uninstalled, you must disable Google Play Protect.

how to Disable Google Play Protect

Comment: Voting to close as this is a question about how to use an android device, not how to program one

Answer (score 2):

Make your package name same as your project path

eg: suppose your package name is com.application.project  and your application folder path is com.example.xyz.project this will give you an error.

Comment: how to fix this issue please ,what i should do

Comment: Either rename package to com.example.xyz.project or change application folder path

Comment: @RohitLalwani Where is defined the application folder path?

Comment: check the folder structure on left side panel